# Image not displaying in Algolia search magento2

Tags: magento2, product-images, search, algolia

I have installed Algolia search extension in our magento2 store.

The extension is working properly but one issue is that images are not displaying when the search is made.

In all other pages like list page, detail page and search result page products are displaying correctly.

I have followed below help link from the extension providers.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/integration/magento-2/troubleshooting/general-faq/#missing-images-during-search

I make sure all the settings are configured correctly, but still images are not loading for me.

If anyone have faced the same issue, please look into it and help me to resolve the error.

Thanks

Comment: What are the URLs of the images that are not showing?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are using /pub as root directory?

If this is the case then you have to login in the backend and go into **Shops -> Configuration -> Algolia -> Advanced** and set **Remove pub/ from image URLs** to **yes**

Comment: I have done this change, and re-indexed but no luck